# How to get a a fragment activity in the Android Studio Designer?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I try to follow the Google tutorial for [view models](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html). I created a custom view class holding a view model and I want to apply this view class within the Android Studio Designer into a layout.

When it comes to getting the view model by a factory method, it wants a `Fragment` or `FragmentActivity` as a parameter to the method **`ViewModelProviders.of(Fragment activity)`**. In the tutorials example `this` is `AppCompatActivity` which extends `FragmentActivity`.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders
              .of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
           [...]
    }
}
```

Now I am in my custom view class. I access the context by `getContext()` and cast to `FragmentActivity`. This does not work as expected in the designer. It complains:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

How do I handle this? Am I forced to create a fragment first, only to be able to use a view model, even if I don't need a fragment at all?

To add the relevant sections of my class:

```
public class MathKeyboardView extends ConstraintLayout {

    // ------ snip ----------

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        // ------ snip ----------

        if(!isInEditMode()) {
            getDisplayViewModel().observe(
                    (FragmentActivity) getContext(), new Observer<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable String number) {
                            display.setText(number);
                        }
                    });
            reset();
        }
    }

    private DisplayViewModel getDisplayViewModel() {
        return ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) getContext()).get(DisplayViewModel.class);
    }
```

Here I already added the `if(!isInEditMode())` condition, which is maybe the solution, maybe a wrong approach.

Comment: casting is wrong. Show me your MyViewModel

Comment: I surrounded the dynamic parts of the code by `if(!isInEditMode())` condition. Now I can use the custom view in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` of your `View` has been "wrapped" in a `ContextThemeWrapper` to change the theme. You can use `ContextWrapper.getBaseContext()` to find the "real" `Context` object:

```
(FragmentActivity) ((ContextWrapper) getContext()).getBaseContext()
```

Comment: Thank you. This does not solve the Android Studio issue, but it makes the code running in my application again. 

Now in theory the view should not lose data upon rotation. In practice it still does. Seems I did not catch the right context by this approach. Any further idea?

Comment: In Android Studio the message changed to "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity".

Comment: Ah! It's the reset() method deleting the data upon rotation. Basically it works.